# How to break markers drawing which is in progress

Tags: leaflet, html5

The following leaflet codes draws a series of markers one by one. I don't want to wait until all points are drawn. How to break the drawing process before it ends and clear the screen?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Break Draw</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="leaflet.css" />
  <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.6.2/leaflet-src.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Popcen.css" />
  <script src="leaflet.js"></script>
  <script src="leaflet-google.js"></script>
  <script src="leaflet.groupedlayercontrol.js"></script>
  <script src="districtar.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="span9" style="height:100%">
      <div id="map" style="position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;             z-index: 9999; width: 100%; height: 100%">
      <div id="button-information">
          <input type="button" id="btnSummary" value="Hit Sequence" onclick="myHit()"     class="btnStyle span2" />
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
<script>
function myHit()
{
    var geojson = { type: 'LineString', coordinates: [[29.07, 81.51], [29.36, 81.03],     [28.29, 83.73], [27.42, 87.01], [28.85, 82.18], [28.8, 81.92], [28.4, 83.99], 

[28.24, 84.75], [28.41, 85.8], [28.28, 84.72], [28.13, 85.65], [28.2, 85.75], [27.99,     85.71], [27.78, 85.84], [27.9, 84.86], [28.18, 84.95], [27.65, 85.63], [27.91, 85.33], 

[28, 85.6], [28.29, 85.16], [27.87, 85.8], [27.86, 85.85], [27.91, 85.5], [28.14, 85.28], [28, 85.4], [27.82, 86.05], [28.16, 84.71], [28.1, 85.2], [27.69, 86.02], [27.79, 

85.16], [27.68, 85.32], [27.73, 85.9], [28.05, 85.25], [27.6, 86.09], [27.73, 85.9],     [28.14, 85.16], [27.95, 85.56], [27.92, 85.64], [27.8, 85.29], [27.77, 85.83], [27.9, 

85.53], [27.78, 85.17], [28.34, 85.91], [28.1, 85.27], [27.78, 85.98], [27.94, 85.55], [27.71, 85.43], [27.93, 85.56], [28.05, 85.35], [28.14, 84.71], [27.93, 85.56], [28.25, 

85.83], [28.24, 84.82], [27.6, 85.96], [27.98, 84.99], [27.82, 85.8], [27.99, 85.02], [27.69, 85.25], [27.67, 86.07], [28.05, 85.34], [27.67, 85.28]] };

     var hitSequence = L.marker([26, 80]).addTo(map);
     var t = 0;
     window.setInterval(function() {
          hitSequence.setLatLng(L.latLng(
          geojson.coordinates[t][0],
          geojson.coordinates[t][1]));
       t += 1;
     }, 100);
     }
</script>
<script>    
    var map = L.map('map', {zoomControl: false, maxZoom: 12}).setView([28.1,84.1], 7);

    L.control.scale({position: 'topleft'}).addTo(map);
    new L.Control.Zoom({ position: 'topleft' }).addTo(map);

    function voidDist(feature) {
        return {
            fillColor: 'transparent',
            weight: 1,
            opacity: 1,
            color: '#000000',
            dashArray: '1 7',
            fillOpacity: 0.7
        };
    }

    var plainDist = new L.geoJson(districtar, {
        style: voidDist,
          onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
            layer.bindPopup("District:  " + feature.properties.DNAME);
        }
        });

    map.addLayer(plainDist);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simple javascript to cancel the `setInterval` you created:

```
var handle = setInterval(function() {
    // do something
}, 100);

function onCancel() {
    if (handle) clearInterval(handle);
}
```

Here's a working example using your code: http://jsfiddle.net/umwo0rn1/25/